# Can parse the content uri

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

StartActivity Class

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    FloatingActionButton newContact = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.add_new);
    newContact.setOnClickListener(this);
    String n = DataProvider.mTable1Uri;
    Uri un = Uri.parse(n);
    Cursor c = managedQuery(un, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Toast.makeText(this,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(table0coloum.mFirstName)),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.add_new :
            Intent addN = new Intent(StartActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(addN);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

EditText firstName,middleName,lastName,phone,email,address;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initilize();
    FloatingActionButton save = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.save_save);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initilize() {
    firstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.save_firstName);
    middleName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.save_middleName);
    lastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.save_lastName);
    phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.save_phoneNo);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.save_Email);
    address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.save_address);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.save_save :
            saveToTable();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Save",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

private void saveToTable() {
    ContentValues val =new ContentValues();
    if(!firstName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        val.put(table0coloum.mFirstName,firstName.getText().toString());
    }
    if(!middleName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        val.put(table0coloum.mMiddleName,middleName.getText().toString());
    }
    if(!lastName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        val.put(table0coloum.mLastName,lastName.getText().toString());
    }
    if(!phone.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        val.put(table0coloum.mPhoneNo,phone.getText().toString());
    }
    if(!email.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        val.put(table0coloum.mEmail,email.getText().toString());
    }
    if(!address.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        val.put(table0coloum.mAddress,address.getText().toString());
    }
    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.mContentUri, val);
    clearFileds();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void clearFileds() {
    firstName.setText("");
    middleName.setText("");
    lastName.setText("");
    phone.setText("");
    email.setText("");
    address.setText("");
}
}
```

DataProvider Class

```
public class DataProvider extends ContentProvider{

public static final String mBaseAuthority = "com.nexus.nsnik.contentsave";

public static final String mBaseUri = "content://"+mBaseAuthority;

public static final String mTable1Uri = mBaseUri+"/"+Table.mTableName;

public static final Uri mContentUri = Uri.parse(mTable1Uri);

private static final int mFirstLastName = 1;
private static final int mAllData = 2;

private static HashMap<String, String> mContactProjectionMap;

private SQLiteDatabase sbt;

public static final UriMatcher uriMatch ;

static {
    uriMatch = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatch.addURI(mTable1Uri,Table.mTableName+"/#",mFirstLastName);
    uriMatch.addURI(mTable1Uri,Table.mTableName,mAllData);
}


public static class Databse extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String mDataBaseName = "contactdb";

    private static final int mDataBaseVersion = 2;

    private static final String mDropTable = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table.mTableName;


    public Databse(Context context) {
        super(context, mDataBaseName, null, mDataBaseVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String table = "CREATE TABLE "+ Table.mTableName + " ("
                + table0coloum.mUid + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + table0coloum.mFirstName + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + table0coloum.mMiddleName + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + table0coloum.mLastName + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + table0coloum.mPhoneNo + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + table0coloum.mEmail + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + table0coloum.mAddress + " VARCHAR(255)"
                +");";
        db.execSQL(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(mDropTable);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    Databse dbt = new Databse(getContext());
    sbt = dbt.getWritableDatabase();
    return(sbt==null)? false:true ;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder sqb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    sqb.setTables(Table.mTableName);
    switch (uriMatch.match(uri))
    {
        case mFirstLastName :
            sqb.appendWhere( table0coloum.mUid+ "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
            break;
        case mAllData :
            sqb.setProjectionMap(mContactProjectionMap);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == ""){
        sortOrder = table0coloum.mFirstName;
    }
    Cursor c = sqb.query(sbt,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
    return c;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (uriMatch.match(uri))
    {
        case mFirstLastName :
            return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vdn.com.nexus.nsnik.contentsave";
        case mAllData :
            return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vdn.com.nexus.nsnik.contentsave";
    }
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    long  insertId = sbt.insert(Table.mTableName,null,values);
    if (insertId>0)
    {
        Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(mContentUri, insertId);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
        return _uri;
    }
    throw new SQLException("Failed to add a record into " + uri);
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int count = 0;
    switch (uriMatch.match(uri))
    {
        case mFirstLastName :
            String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            count = sbt.delete( Table.mTableName, table0coloum.mFirstName +  " = " + id +
                    (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
            break;
        case mAllData :
            count = sbt.delete(Table.mTableName, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int count = 0;
    switch (uriMatch.match(uri))
    {
        case mFirstLastName :
            String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
            count = sbt.update( Table.mTableName, values,table0coloum.mFirstName +  " = " + id +
                    (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
            break;
        case mAllData :
            count = sbt.update(Table.mTableName, values,selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nexus.nsnik.contentsave">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.nexus.nsnik.contentsave"
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".DataProvider">
    </provider>
</application>
```

On start of the code it get this error :

Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nexus.nsnik.contentsave/com.nexus.nsnik.contentsave.StartActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI content://com.nexus.nsnik.contentsave/contactable

its my first time trying content provider so excuse me for this question, but i cant understand this error, like why can it parse the uri

Answer (score 0):

I think your source includes `StartActivity.this`, try removing the class name from that so your left with `this` as the parameter.